# MySQL - 0 [ERROR] Error in accept: Bad file descriptor

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

Recently upgraded to MySQL 5.7.12 on a Debian (Debian 3.2.78-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and have been running into the server hanging after every few hours. This is getting flooded in the syslog and mysql.log:

`2016-06-13T18:05:20.261209Z 0 [ERROR] Error in accept: Bad file descriptor`

MySQL info:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12-5, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  6.2

Pieces of **my.cnf** **mysqld** section that can guide some assistance on tweaking values:

```html
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_stack            = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 8

max_connections         = 150
max_connect_errors      = 10000
connect_timeout         = 30
wait_timeout            = 86400
table_open_cache        = 2048
open_files_limit        = 65535

query_cache_limit       = 4M
query_cache_size        = 128M
query_cache_type    = 1

server-id               = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

# * InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
thread_pool_size = 24
```

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue on a Ubuntu 16.04 system with mysql 5.7.13 . We increased our max open files parameter in systemd like this:

**/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/10-ulimit.conf**

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=1000000
```

So far the issue did not happen again. Maybe mysql needs somehow more file descriptors now.

Comment: Just a heads-up- On my FC24 system when updating mariadb with DNF, the systemd file was overwritten and this problem recurred.

Comment: Unfortunately this fix didn't work here. I've encountered this error on fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10 instances with MySQL 5.7.17. (BTW I think it's necessary to make the mysql.service folder first and run `systemctl daemon-reload`).

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem (or possibly one of the problems).  Here is an extract from strace on mysqld:

```
...
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 20
write(2, "2017-01-29T22:22:45.433033Z 0 [N"..., 72) = 72
setsockopt(20, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(20, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, [0], 4) = 0
bind(20, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(3306), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
listen(20, 70)                          = 0
fcntl(20, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(20, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
 ...
accept(20, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(58332), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:127.0.0.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 37
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [CHLD], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f3ddeac84b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
getpeername(37, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(58332), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:127.0.0.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
getsockname(37, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(3306), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:127.0.0.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
open("/etc/hosts.allow", O_RDONLY)      = 38
fstat(38, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=589, ...}) = 0
read(38, "# /etc/hosts.allow: list of host"..., 4096) = 589
read(38, "", 4096)                      = 0
close(38)                               = 0
open("/etc/hosts.deny", O_RDONLY)       = 38
fstat(38, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=704, ...}) = 0
read(38, "# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts"..., 4096) = 704
close(38)                               = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 38
connect(38, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(38, "<36>Jan 29 14:23:08 mysqld[13052"..., 72, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 72
shutdown(20, SHUT_RDWR)                 = 0
close(20)                               = 0

poll([{fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=22, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=20, revents=POLLNVAL}])
accept(-1, 0x7ffe6ebd7160, 0x7ffe6ebd70fc) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
write(2, "2017-01-29T22:23:08.109451Z 0 [E"..., 75) = 75
 ... rinse and repeat *REALLY* fast!
```

In locking down my system with tcp_wrappers I had inadvertently taken mysqld out of both hosts.allow and hosts.deny.  It seems that after checking both hosts.allow and hosts.deny mysqld shuts down and closes the socket as you might expect.  However it them immediately starts to poll the (now non-existent) socket for activity.

I just did another test where my tcp_wrappers was correctly configured.  When I connect from an authorized host all is fine; however when I connected from a blocked address the same issue occurs.  Based on this I recommend using other tools to secure mysqld and making your tcp_wrappers config more open than your firewall.  That being said the bug should still be fixed!

This fix has yet to stand the test of time so, as usual, YMMV.  Hope it helps anyway

Nick

Comment: I had the exact same problem (log flooded with the "bad file descriptor" message and MySQL not working) and searched a lot until I found this post. In my case, it was fail2ban that for some reason added 127.0.0.1 to /etc/hosts.deny to completely mess up the system!

As soon as I removed it (and added localhost to /etc/hosts.allow to prevent this from happening in the future), things went back to normal.

And the morale of the story: As a precaution, add 127.0.0.1 to /etc/hosts.allow just to make sure fail2ban does not get in your way!

Comment: I added some mysqld options to hosts.allow and hosts.deny, then removed them when I found that MySQL Workbench wouldn't connect properly. The messages mentioned in the question flooded my error.log file until I ran out of disk space. I stopped the mysql service, compressed that log file, and rebooted. All seems well now. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Researched a bit and found following;

1. Present in MariaDB also

   https://lists.launchpad.net/maria-discuss/msg03060.html
   https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-8995
2. Percona Server/Percona XtraDB Cluster

   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/percona-discussion/Tu0S2OvYqKA
3. Old bug from 2010/2012

   https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48929
   http://lists.mysql.com/commits/96472
4. Some interesting information (should never happen)

   https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/97275

[I work for Percona]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after upgrading to Percona Cluster 5.7.14-26.17-1.trusty.

The ulimit.conf suggestion doesn't help, and I've made sure that there are sufficient file handles, so far as I can tell, by editing /etc/security/limits.conf and /etc/sysctl.conf.

I can reproduce this easily by telnetting to post 3306 and then disconnecting; the server then goes into a spin logging this error.

A horrible workaround for this, which looks promising in my environment, is to avoid using TCP connections on port 3306, and use unix sockets instead.

You can proxy from port 3306 to the socket by changing the port number in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and then using socat

```
nohup socat TCP4-LISTEN:3306,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock&
```

If I then telnet in on port 3306 and disconnect, I can't provoke the problem.  I intend to report back on how well this stands up over time.

FWIW, the code looks as though it expects this to happen sometimes:

```
for (uint retry= 0; retry < MAX_ACCEPT_RETRY; retry++)
{
  socket_len_t length= sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
  connect_sock= mysql_socket_accept(key_socket_client_connection, listen_sock,
                                    (struct sockaddr *)(&cAddr), &length);
  if (mysql_socket_getfd(connect_sock) != INVALID_SOCKET ||
      (socket_errno != SOCKET_EINTR && socket_errno != SOCKET_EAGAIN))
    break;
}
if (mysql_socket_getfd(connect_sock) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
  /*
    accept(2) failed on the listening port, after many retries.
    There is not much details to report about the client,
    increment the server global status variable.
  */
  connection_errors_accept++;
  if ((m_error_count++ & 255) == 0) // This can happen often
    sql_print_error("Error in accept: %s", strerror(errno));
  if (socket_errno == SOCKET_ENFILE || socket_errno == SOCKET_EMFILE)
    sleep(1);             // Give other threads some time
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The socat workaround, though ugly, is holding up fine, so I recommend it to anyone else who's hitting this.  It looks like this is a problem that's been around a while, and must only affect some environments (see Google and @Roel below).

Comment: An update.  With the socat workaround in place I still see some loops producing these errors, but they seem to terminate eventually, and so the system is broadly stable.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same error and none of the solutions worked BUT after some research on our end we found that it was apparmor that was denying our logging directory causing the bad file descriptors error message.